# Are there any "pure function" persistent cache implementation being built around ray-project?

Tags: persistence, memoization, stateless, ray

Dask has some caching (but not really persistent) through the pure (stateless) delayed interface. And there are a number of custom frameworks out there for handling layers of caching of pure function (DAGs). Basically, one always ends up with a pattern of layers of persistant plus in-memory caches and some attempts at data-affinity within the scheduling framework.

Is this something that the ray-project will be looking at or another project built on top of ray?

Comment: I see this for example: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/1157

Comment: Currently there aren't any plans to add this to the Ray backend. It seems natural to implement it at the application level (or to have a helper library for it as you mention). What are the scenarios where this feature would be really beneficial?

Comment: Compute dags with versioned functions and versioned data. Even semi-persistent for intermediate results could be useful. All large institutions really.